# Tourist visa expired before travel to Dubai; what can I do?

Tags: visas, dubai

My tourist visa for Dubai expired 4 days before my planned travel there. What are my options?

Comment: Get a new visa?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your nationality is one that requires a visa to visit Dubai, you should, as Tom so ably puts it: **get a new visa**. An expired visa will not be accepted, and the airline should not allow you to board unless you have the travel documents required for entry.

If there is not sufficient time to get a new visa, you will have to delay your trip, though you can always try conveying the nature of your urgency to the proper authorities if this trip is an emergency. If your nationality and purpose of travel makes you eligible for a visa on arrival or an e-visa, then you should pursue that option.

Comment: I thought you could get tourist Visa's at the border for 100USD or something? Maybe best calling the airport in Turkey and asking them

Comment: @ppumkin The rules will depend on your nationality and purpose of travel (tourism, transit, employment, etc...), which is why I included that caveat at the beginning. If you're eligible for a visa on arrival or an e-visa, then obviously you should do that. We don't know the OP's nationality or why he's visiting Dubai, but the fact that he had an old visa is a decent clue he might require a new visa of some kind.